# The error "numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index" can be related with numpy version?

Tags: python, numpy

Thank you for taking time to help me with this problem.
I´m using numpy 1.14.2. When I add TempLake[len(Z)-1] to the following line I get this error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an index. Can this be caused by the version of numpy?

```
Causes no error
d[len(Z)-1]=alfa[len(Z)-1]*s[len(Z)-1]*TempLake[len(Z)-2]*(Kt[len(Z)-2]+2.0*Kt[len(Z)-1])+[1+alfa[len(Z)-1]*s[len(Z)-1]*(Kt[len(Z)-2]+2*Ktplus1[len(z)-1])]

Causes error
d[len(Z)-1]=alfa[len(Z)-1]*s[len(Z)-1]*TempLake[len(Z)-2]*(Kt[len(Z)-2]+2.0*Kt[len(Z)-1])+[1+alfa[len(Z)-1]*s[len(Z)-1]*(Kt[len(Z)-2]+2*Ktplus1[len(z)-1])]*TempLake[len(Z)-1]
```

Comment: why put the intermediate result in a list?

Comment: I don´t understand what you mean

Comment: You create a list `[1+alpha...`. Is it intended?

Comment: No it´s not intended...its working now thank so much

Comment: You didn't notice this because there is too much duplication in your code. I suggest you to get rid of it.

Comment: What is `TempLake`?  list, ndarray?  `numpy` has been tightening the requirements on indices, removing previous sloppiness that allowed floats.  Without your installed version I can't reproduce your error message.